# How to fix regex Unterminated regular expression literal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex

I currently have this regex string and i am getting a Unterminated regular expression literal error in my react code

```
const check_number = /^[0]\d{10}$)|(^[\+]?[234]\d{12}$
```

does anyone know how to fix this.

Comment: You could try `/^(?:0|\+?[234]\d\d)\d{10}$/` instead

Answer (score 1):

The exact syntax error is being caused by a missing `/` ending delimiter (and a few other things).  But, your regex has other problems.  Use this version:

```js
const check_number = /^(?:0\d{10}|[+]?[234]\d{12})$/
```

The above pattern matches phone numbers which either:

- Start with zero and have 11 total digits, or
- Start with an optional +, followed by 2, 3, or 4, and have 13 total digits

Answer (score -1):

The problem is you have an invalid regular expression, for a number of reasons:

1. You are missing a closing `/` character at the end
2. You have a closing parenthesis in the start with no opening parenthesis
3. You have an opening parenthesis in the middle with no closing paren